# How can I create two distinct sets of exposed filters for use in a single view?

Tags: views

I am wondering if there is a way to create two distinct sets of exposed filters to use on a single view. The reasoning is that I have a view for content of a given type. I have a set of views exposed filters placed in the header of the site that is used as a search form, which displays its results within this view. However, once the user submits a search, I would like them to be able to further filter their results based on aspects of the resulting nodes. This would somehow require a second set of exposed filters for the same view. As far as I can tell, as long as I have my exposed filters in a block, all filters that I add are placed within that block. Is there some way to get around this, and display two sets of filters, in different places, for a single view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are describing is faceted search. In Drupal, a good solution for faceted search is using [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) along with the [Apache Solr module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). [Here's](http://nickveenhof.be/blog/screencast-1-installing-apache-solr-module-and-server-drupal-7) a video tutorial on how to install Solr for Drupal. [Here](http://www.timeforkids.com/search/site/kids) you can see an example of faceted search working on a site I built for the company I currently work for.

Comment: I'm using the view in conjunction with a Search API index, but hadn't seen any faceted options so I wasn't sure what that meant (although, Search API says that it supports facets). It must be because I am using a Database Index instead of Solr. The tutorial that you linked to, and the ones that I have found online, both refer to setting up Solr on a local machine. Does this mean that the site uses my machine to search, and that my machine has to be running and connected to the internet for the searches on my site to function?

Comment: It means that you should set up Solr on your production server. You should set up Solr on your local machine only for testing and development.

Comment: Oh, I see. I suppose that means looking into hosting options that support its installation, then. Bummer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could install Solr on your own server, or you could use [Acquia Search](http://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-network/cloud-services/acquia-search). At my previous job we had our Drupal hosted on Rackspace and our Solr search at Acquia. Your site can communicate with Acquia's Solr via the [aqcuia_connector](http://drupal.org/project/acquia_connector) module.